# Click links one by one with Selenium webdriver Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I make script which search for me intersted set of strings, but i have error.
How i can resolve below problem:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath")

for x in range(0, len(links)):
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    links[x].click()
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        DO something
        driver.back()
        print("Mission completed!!")
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
        driver.back()
        print("No action")

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
in line: links[x].click()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you re-directed to new page elements from your list `links` become stale- you cannot use them anymore.

You can use below code instead:

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath")]
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # DO something
```

This should allow you to get list of references and get each page in a loop

Comment: thx man! You teach me a lot piece of good code :) This is the best wat to do this? My website look the same like google after search with 20 links.

Comment: If there is only one page with 20 links you can use it as it is, but if you have pagination (multiple pages with 20 links on each), then you might do another loop clicking `Next` button to append links from each page and then go through provided loop. One loop- to gather links, one- to follow links from list of references

Answer (score 1):

What does clicking on the links do? If you navigate to another page after clicking it, then the next one in the iteration is no longer in the DOM, effectively becoming **stale**.